# I want to read a local text file on my computer on an Android Emulator

Tags: android, file, android-emulator

How can I put that file in userdata.img so that the emulator can read it? Also, how can to specifiy the path of the file in the code? I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push a file onto the emulator or any other rooted device you'd just issue a `adb push` command.

```
adb push FILE PATH_ON_DEVICE
```

In Java to define the path to a file you can simply create a [`File`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) object with the path set in its constructor.

```
File file = new File("/path/on/device");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use adb to push the file to whatever location you want. Just start the emulator (without any device connected) and type

```
adb push myfile /mylocation/myfile
```

Here is the manual page for the commands: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

Alternatively, you can browse the file system using [ddms](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html)

Comment: I tried "adb push C:\song.mp3 /system/somg.mp3". But it gives an error saying that it is a Read Only File System

Comment: I found the solution to the problem. First I remounted adb using adb remount. Then it should work

Comment: Try to avoid writing on the /system folder, as you have good chances of corrupting it. Use /sdcard instead (create a folder using `adh shell` and `mkdir /sdcard/myfolder/`)

Comment: Aleadam is right. There is a good reason for making the `/system` directory read-only.